# add custom class to wysihtml5 text editor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I'd like to be able to add a button that adds my own custom class. I don't see this in the documentation anywhere but seems like a common request.

For example.

Highlighting "Some Text" and pressing the button "Custom Class" will add

`<p class="wysiwyg-custom-class">Some Text</p`>

Comment: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.getElementsByClassName),[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList)
,[3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), [bonus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)
this is documentation you looked for ?

Comment: As stated in the title this is for wysihtml5 text editor. I need to be able to highlight the text and add a custom class. It's more complicated than just adding a class though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define new command, my example is based on [ForeColor](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/src/commands/foreColor.js):

```
(function(wysihtml5) {
    
  wysihtml5.commands.setClass = {
    exec: function(composer, command, element_class) {
        element_class=element_class.split(/:/);
        element=element_class[0];
        newclass=element_class[1];
      var REG_EXP = new RegExp(newclass,'g');
    //register custom class
      wysihtml5ParserRules['classes'][newclass]=1;

      return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.exec(composer, command, element, newclass, REG_EXP);
    },

    state: function(composer, command, element_class) {
        element_class=element_class.split(/:/);
        element=element_class[0];
        newclass=element_class[1];
        var REG_EXP = new RegExp(newclass,'g');
      return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.state(composer, command, element, newclass, REG_EXP);
    }
  };
})(wysihtml5);
```

usage:

HTML:

```
<div id="uxToolbar">
   <button data-wysihtml5-command="setClass" data-wysihtml5-command-value="span:my-wysihtml5-custom-class" type="button" title="View HTML" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-mini">
       My class
   </button>
</div>
```

so as you can see value is from two parts: `element:class`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nkkek/)

Comment: I got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: wysihtml5ParserRules is not defined, using your code.

Comment: @user437797 I update fiddle demo, to get javascript with correct mime types: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nkkek/ so my code works fine. If you have the problem with modifications of this code - ask new question.